# Dynamically change data of Custom PreferenceScreen

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferencescreen

I am working on custom `PreferenceScreen`, I have created a custom screen for the settings page using `PreferenceActivity`.

Below is my preference screen.

[image]

**Issue:-**
I need to change badge of Download data dynamically. 
I followed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334194/custom-preferencescreen-with-clickable-buttons) for achieve this layout.
I already tried all answer of that question but not working single answer.

Is there any other way to find View which is inside preference?

**settings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<Preference android:title="@string/settings_user_profile" android:key="user_profile" android:summary="@string/settings_user_profile_desc" android:layout="@layout/setting_list"></Preference>
<Preference android:title="@string/settings_download" android:key="download_data" android:summary="@string/settings_download_desc" android:layout="@layout/setting_list"></Preference>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: post your setting xml file code

Comment: Check updated question... My code is same as that question, look at that question ....

Comment: Will that be okay for you to use activity instead of preferences

Comment: I will go with @StinePike's suggestion, good

Comment: there are lots of preference around 20-25 including list/checkbox, so PreferenceActivity better to activity..

Comment: why? cant you inflate layout in Activity?

Comment: @hotveryspicy after then, I have to create lots of dialog, have to commit Preference manually, it will be vast code if I use activity..

Comment: some of things you need to do in preferece activity too, isn't it? then why not to go with full control?

Comment: @CapDroid try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997007/how-to-access-widgets-set-in-layout-using-preference-activity)

Comment: @Mitesh let me check bro..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can subclass `Preference`, overriding `onBindDialogView()` - just remember to change the XML from `<Preference...>` to include your package and class `<com.example.app.BadgedPreference...>`:

```
@Override
protected void onBindDialogView(View v) {
    super.onBindDialogView(v);
    Log.v( "onBindDialogView()", v.getClass().getSimpleName() );
}
```

If your `BadgedPreference` has a method for handling your change, you can use it a bit more easily - from within your `PreferenceActivity`:

```
PreferenceScreen myPrefScreen = (PreferenceScreen)getPreferenceScreen();
BadgedPreference bp = (BadgedPreference)myPrefScreen.findPreference("download_data");
// Custom method
bp.setBadgeValue(12);
```

Even more simply, you can use a standard `Preference`, just style its summary field as a 'badge', then you can set the value using the included Summary field:

```
Preference pref = (Preference)myPrefScreen.findPreference("download_data");
pref.setSummary("12");
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`
Something like this:

```
  @Override
  public void onResume() {
      super.onResume();

      // Set up a listener whenever a key changes
      getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
         .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);        
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
       super.onPause();

      // Unregister the listener whenever a key changes
      getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
         .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
        String key) {

       //update summary  
       updatePrefsSummary(sharedPreferences, findPreference(key));
  }
```

If you use standard Preference you can try something like this:

```
/**
 * Update summary
 * 
 * @param sharedPreferences
 * @param pref
 */
 protected void updatePrefsSummary(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
    Preference pref) {

if (pref == null)
    return;

if (pref instanceof ListPreference) {
    // List Preference
    ListPreference listPref = (ListPreference) pref;
    listPref.setSummary(listPref.getEntry());

} else if (pref instanceof EditTextPreference) {
    // EditPreference
    EditTextPreference editTextPref = (EditTextPreference) pref;
    editTextPref.setSummary(editTextPref.getText());

} else if (pref instanceof MultiSelectListPreference) {
    // MultiSelectList Preference
    MultiSelectListPreference mlistPref = (MultiSelectListPreference) pref;
    String summaryMListPref = "";
    String and = "";

    // Retrieve values
    Set<String> values = mlistPref.getValues();
    for (String value : values) {
        // For each value retrieve index
        int index = mlistPref.findIndexOfValue(value);
        // Retrieve entry from index
        CharSequence mEntry = index >= 0
                && mlistPref.getEntries() != null ? mlistPref
                .getEntries()[index] : null;
        if (mEntry != null) {
            // add summary
            summaryMListPref = summaryMListPref + and + mEntry;
            and = ";";
        }
    }
    // set summary
    mlistPref.setSummary(summaryMListPref);

} else if (pref instanceof RingtonePreference) {
    // RingtonePreference
    RingtonePreference rtPref = (RingtonePreference) pref;
    String uri;
    if (rtPref != null) {
        uri = sharedPreferences.getString(rtPref.getKey(), null);
        if (uri != null) {
            Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(
                    getActivity(), Uri.parse(uri));
                pref.setSummary(ringtone.getTitle(getActivity()));
        }
    }

}
```

}

If you use custom preference, you can do everything, and you can override setSummary(int value)

```
@Override
public void setSummary(int value) {
   setSummary(String.valueOf(value)+" ...." );
}
```